# 500 internal server error in WordPress' widgets not getting fixed

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am getting blank screen on wp backend Appearance >> Widgets page.
When I checked under network tab in chrome, it shows 500 internal server error for widgets.php
I have tried everything from last 3-4 days from increasing memory limit to addin extra handlers in .htaccess. I have tried everything through which i have been fixing it previously on some sites but now this has driven me crazy :(
Can anyone help with any solution of this?

Comment: Have you checked `Apache` error log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone else who is trying to find solution. Check your error log file. Through turning on WP_DEBUG too you cant see all error so better to check Apache log. I checked it and found that it was due to a plugin.

Comment: What plugin? What was the error? What did you do to correct it? Please give more info for other users to see.

Comment: This was due to Tag Manager plugin 
`[Sun Mar 29 13:08:25 2015] [error] [client 58.27.150.193] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 131072 bytes) in /path/to/host/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-tag-cloud-widget/src/Widget.php on line 218` This is what i seen in error log. i was already doubting that it might be memory problem and when i checked, yes it was memory problem as mentioned above.

Comment: I removed that plugin and it was back to normal. now i will use some other plugin instead of Ultimate Tag Cloud Widget.